# Expo-Image-Picker in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker, imagepicker

**Is there a way to limit video recording time using ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync()?**

My code:

```
captureVideoObject = async () => {
        return await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
            allowsEditing: true,
            quality: 1,
            aspect: [16, 9],
        });
    }
```

No way around for durationLimit as react-native-image-picker does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [expo-image-picker v8.3.0](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/), ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync() comes with inbuilt video controls, of which you can monitor the video recording duration via it's GUI but not programmatically.
Alternatively, you can achieve limiting video duration programmatically with [expo-camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)